# Difference Between "Keine Ahnung" and "Ich weiß nicht"?

Tags: meaning, phrase

As I said in the title:

What is the difference between "Keine Ahnung" and "Ich weiß nicht"?

They both roughly mean I do not know.

Keine Ahnung literally translated is "No Idea"

Is Ich weiß nicht litterally translated "I white not" or "I do not know"?

What are the different uses between them (What are each used for)?

And if you could, explain how "I white not" became "I do not know".

Comment: _""I white not""_ is nonsense. The correct translation of _Ich weiss nicht_ to english is _I don't know_.

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually asking about (pun intended).

Comment: Unfortunately [Google Translate](https://translate.google.de/#en/de/I%20white%20not) gets that wrong. Not into the other direction though (for both written forms).

Comment: Where did you "to white" get from? Doesn't it mean e.g. turning something white?

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser Wouldn't that be [_to whiten_](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/whiten) and declined appropriately?

Comment: "weiß" --> "white", but that is the adjective. OTOH, "weiß", a form of the verb "wissen" (to know) means "know" or "knows", depending on the person. "Ich weiß nicht" means literally "I do not know".

Comment: BTW I'm trying to correct google translate about that: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/translate/Ngpb-1m-Nn0;context-place=forum/translate

Comment: I think you can find the difference in the structure. First case Ahnung is a noun second case you have a verb. So the translations are what you wrote. The word weiß has nothing to do with white here, also it would be written with a capital W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between "Keine Ahnung" and "Ich weiß nicht" is, that "Keine Ahnung" is more rough, you wouldn't say it for instance to your boss/superior. In the bottom line, they both mean the same.

Comment: _"you wouldn't say it for instance to your boss/superior"_ Depends on the quality of their question and your balls :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's right, of course :D But if you don't want to take some risks, you wouldn't use it

Comment: If you really don't want to _take risk_, you'd better say neither, but cant in depth knowledge about the topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can cant be translated in your sentence as "heucheln"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say. One of my fav translations is "Phrasen dreschen" :-D

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To answer your comment above,  I think your right, I mixed it. But I found the verb to white , too, as "weißen" and "kalken"

Comment: Sure, but _weisseln_ / _weissen_ is a dialect verb for _weiss anstreichen_ IIRC. And comments should be responded in the appropriate comment thread BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As is said, I got downvoted to less than 50 reputation, so I can no longer write comments to the question itsself

Comment: Oops, I've been overlooking that :-)